# How can I align tikz nodes ragged left?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles, nodes

I'm producing a CV from a template which uses tikz nodes for a general skills section. This is what the section looks like:

[image]

I would like the nodes to be left-aligned in relation to one another, however currently it appears they're justified on the page.

This is the code used to produce these nodes:

```
    \section{General Skills}
    \smallskip % additional skip because tag outlines use up space
    \tag{Good Written and Verbal communication}{A}{}
    \tag{Can work to a deadline}{B}{}
    \tag{Analytical/ Scientific approach to work}{}{}
    \tag{Work well in a team}{}{}
    \tag{Can simply communicate complex ideas}{}{}
```

and this is the code used to produce the tag command:

```
\newcommand{\tag}[3]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base, draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex, #3] (#2) {#1};
}
```

I have tried using arguments to add optional arguments to the `\node` command, but that doesn't seem to work. For example, for argument 3, I have tried adding `right=1em of A.east` in the second tag, but that just shifts the second tag down slightly. What can I do to stop these nodes from justifying?

Comment: Please provide MWE which reproduce your problem.

Comment: I use your code in a article class. The problem is not exist. You must provide a MWE include all your settings.

Comment: Your tags are independent tikzpictures. Therefore each one is considered by latex like an independent character. If you want to use relative positioning betweem them, they have to be inside one tikzpicture or into independent but "remembered" tikzpictures.

Answer (score 1):

With a `tabular` you don't have to change your `tag` definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{body}{red}

\newcommand{\tag}[3]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base, draw=body!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex,text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex, #3] (#2) {#1};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
    \tag{Good Written and Verbal communication}{A}{} &
    \tag{Can work to a deadline}{B}{} \\
    \tag{Analytical/ Scientific approach to work}{}{} &
    \tag{Work well in a team}{}{}  \\
    \tag{Can simply communicate complex ideas}{}{}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]